# Tables in SPSS Version 24

Tags: spss

I am trying to access tables in SPSS Version 24 but can't find it. Usually it should be on Analyze -> Tables, but I don't have Tables under Analyze.

Thank you

Comment: did you purchase and install the Custom Tables module? if you did and `tables` still doesn't appear look this up: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21480517

Comment: Thank you - I will try and find where SPSS got downloaded to on my PC :)

Answer (score 0):

In a syntax window, issue this command:

`SHOW LICENSE.`

In the Output Viewer a table will appear showing you what you are licensed for.